# Rails is attempting to render remotely... but not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar

I'm working on a rails application and am attempting to convert the [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) gem's "next month" link into an ajax response.

I set the link to remote:

```
  def month_link(month_date)
    link_to I18n.localize(month_date, :format => "%B"),
      {:month => month_date.month, :year => month_date.year},
      remote: true
  end
```

told it to respond to js...

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render text: "help me!" }
end
```

And it works!

```
Started GET "/calendar/2012/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-03 15:27:42 -0500
Processing by CalendarController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"year"=>"2012", "month"=>"6"}
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (('2012-05-27 05:00:00.000000' <= end_at) AND (start_at< '2012-07-01 05:00:00.000000')) ORDER BY start_at ASC
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

*well*... except for the part where it doesn't actually render anything I pass it. If I just tell it to `format.js` w/o the render, it doesn't actually respond to a js file.

**What could cause a render to not display?**

### Updates

- I just noticed that if you access the url like so `localhost:3000/calendar/2012/6.js` It works as expected, So I would assume it's an issue with how the link is set up?
- Ok, I got the js file working, but I have no clue why. I think I was miss-using `render` (although I could have sworn I had used it for debugging purposes once). I guess render only actually render an html page when responding to an html request. Would make sense since it passes json to javascript for ajax requests.
- Another part of the issue was I was trying to use CoffeeScript with either `index.js.coffee.erb` or `index.js.erb.coffee`. I thought it was working for the longest time, but what was really happening, was it was using the original `index.js.erb` I had written first, even though I had already deleted it. Once I restarted the server, everything broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by default the `remote` option ignores any attempts to render or redirect. Considering that the point of Ajax is to prevent both of these... I can see why.

For self reference here is what (to my knowledge) happens when you create a remote `link_to`:

line 51 of jquery_ujs.js

```
  $.rails = rails = {
    // Link elements bound by jquery-ujs
    linkClickSelector: 'a[data-confirm], a[data-method], a[data-remote], a[data-disable-with]',
```

following `linkClickSelector` we find this function at line 300

```
  $(document).delegate(rails.linkClickSelector, 'click.rails', function(e) {
    var link = $(this), method = link.data('method'), data = link.data('params');
    if (!rails.allowAction(link)) return rails.stopEverything(e);

    if (link.is(rails.linkDisableSelector)) rails.disableElement(link);

    if (link.data('remote') !== undefined) {
      if ( (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && (!method || method === 'GET') && !data ) { return true; }

      if (rails.handleRemote(link) === false) { rails.enableElement(link); }
      return false;

    } else if (link.data('method')) {
      rails.handleMethod(link);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Assuming that `handleRemote` handles the AJAX we wind up at line 107 to find this monster

```
// Submits "remote" forms and links with ajax
handleRemote: function(element) {
  var method, url, data, crossDomain, dataType, options;

  if (rails.fire(element, 'ajax:before')) {
    crossDomain = element.data('cross-domain') || null;
    dataType = element.data('type') || ($.ajaxSettings && $.ajaxSettings.dataType);

    if (element.is('form')) {
      method = element.attr('method');
      url = element.attr('action');
      data = element.serializeArray();
      // memoized value from clicked submit button
      var button = element.data('ujs:submit-button');
      if (button) {
        data.push(button);
        element.data('ujs:submit-button', null);
      }
    } else if (element.is(rails.inputChangeSelector)) {
      method = element.data('method');
      url = element.data('url');
      data = element.serialize();
      if (element.data('params')) data = data + "&" + element.data('params');
    } else {
      method = element.data('method');
      url = rails.href(element);
      data = element.data('params') || null;
    }

    options = {
      type: method || 'GET', data: data, dataType: dataType, crossDomain: crossDomain,
      // stopping the "ajax:beforeSend" event will cancel the ajax request
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (settings.dataType === undefined) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', '*/*;q=0.5, ' + settings.accepts.script);
        }
        return rails.fire(element, 'ajax:beforeSend', [xhr, settings]);
      },
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        element.trigger('ajax:success', [data, status, xhr]);
      },
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
        element.trigger('ajax:complete', [xhr, status]);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        element.trigger('ajax:error', [xhr, status, error]);
      }
    };
    // Only pass url to `ajax` options if not blank
    if (url) { options.url = url; }

    return rails.ajax(options);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def month_link(month_date)
  link_to I18n.localize(month_date, :format => "%B"),
  {:remote=>true, :month => month_date.month, :year => month_date.year}
end
```

The format of link_to you are wanting to use is:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

The :remote=>true wants to be in the url_options.  I'm not sure what the :month & :year keys are for,  but if they are html options,  you would want this:

```
def month_link(month_date)
  link_to I18n.localize(month_date, :format => "%B"),
  {:remote=>true}, 
  {:month => month_date.month, :year => month_date.year}
end
```

Comment: `{:month => month_date.month, :year => month_date.year}` are params passed to the index action. My thoughts are that the remote works, otherwise it wouldn't be querying the database, correct?

Comment: @mcmullins Wrong. The action is being called. It's just not being called via Ajax.

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque well, it's working now with the original `link_to` I had set up. It will respond with a javascript file, but not the render action. So I think the render was my issue.

Comment: @RadBrad Although it doesn't explicitly say it in the documentation for link_to, in the [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) docs it lists `:remote` as an **html option**. This would make sense since it only adds the `data-remote` attribute to your html tag.